# jQuery check offset

Tags: jquery, toggle, offset

**HTML:**

```
<ul class="clients">
 <li>
  <div class="over left">Description</div>
  <div class="inner">Image</div>
 </li>
</ul>
```

**CSS:**

```
.clients { margin-right: -20px; }
 .clients li {
  float: left;
  width: 128px;
  height: 120px;
  margin: 0 20px 20px 0;
  border: 1px solid #c2c2c2;
 }
  .clients .over {
   display: none;
   position: absolute;
   width: 250px;
   font-size: 11px;
   line-height: 16px;
   background: #ecf5fb;
   margin: 3px 0 0 3px;
   padding: 18px;
   z-index: 25;
  }
   .clients .right { margin: 3px 0 0 -161px; }
  .clients .inner { width: 128px; height: 120px; overflow: hidden; }
```

So, we have a list of floated squares and a popup blocks in each, which have absolute position.

**JS:**

```
jQuery(function($) {
 $(".clients li").bind('mouseover mouseout',function(){$(this).find("div.over").toggle()});
});
```

If over - show, else - hide. Quite ok, but it must be more advanced, we should catch an offset and give a class to **.over** block:

- if offset from right (corner of browser window) **less** than 150px, then **add class "right"** for an `.over` block.
- if offset from right **more** than 150px - **add class "left"** for an `.over` block.

**How can we do it?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.offset()` returns an object like `{ left: 200, top: 300 }`

`$(window).width()` returns the window width

Clearly you get the left offset streight from `.offset()`. The right offset you need to make a condition with should be calculated as:

```
offsetRight=$(window).width()-$(this).width()-$(this).offset().left;
```

All together:

```
jQuery(function($) {
 $(".clients li").bind('mouseover mouseout',function(){
   $over=$("div.over",this);
   $over.toggle();
   //didn't get if it's the li's offset you need or the actual .over, replace $(this) with $over in next lines if you need that
   offset=$(this).offset();
   offsetRight=$(window).width()-$(this).width()-offset.left;
   if (offsetRight<150){ $over.removeClass('left').addClass('right'); }
   else { $over.removeClass('right').addClass('left'); }
 });
});
```

Comment: can you give a full function? With "if" "else" etc. (if offset from right less than 150px, then add class "right" for an .over block || 
if offset from right more than 150px - add class "left" for an .over block)